# Datatables table data clearing and table destroying not giving a result

Tags: javascript, datatable, destroy

I'm using **DataTables** with Aurelia framework. Table and it's sorting works well, excluding one moment. When I retrieving a new data table should be cleared and redrawn with new data, but I always see rows with data which have been passed before and now.

My ini code:

```
if (this.results && this.results.length > 0) {

    console.log('resultsChanged');

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.table = $('#searchResultsTable').DataTable({
            retrieve: true,
            searching: false,
            paging: false,
            info: false,
            orderMulti: false,
            order: [[2, "asc"]],
            dateFormat: 'dd.mm.YYYY'
        });
    }, 200);
}
```

I have tried to use 'destroy: true' as option, but it restores the first data source, doesn't clear table.

Also I have tried to use this before if condition:

```
if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#searchResultsTable')) {
    console.log('table exists')
    $.fn.dataTable.destroy('#searchResultsTable');
    // $('#searchResultsTable').dataTable.fnDestroy();
}
```

But `$.fn.dataTable.destroy('#searchResultsTable');` always throws an error `$.fn.dataTable.destroy is not a function`.

Looking for you advices and help.

**UPDATE**(*full fucntion*):

```
resultsChanged(): void {

    let timeout = 200;

    if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#searchResultsTable')) {
        console.log('table exists')
        this.table.destroy('#searchResultsTable');
        timeout = 0;
    }

    if (this.results && this.results.length > 0) {

        console.log('resultsChanged');

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.table = $('#searchResultsTable').DataTable({
                retrieve: true,
                searching: false,
                paging: false,
                info: false,
                orderMulti: false,
                order: [[2, "asc"]],
                dateFormat: 'dd.mm.YYYY'
            });
        }, timeout);
    }
}
```

Comment: try changing `$.fn.dataTable.destroy` to `$.fn.DataTable.destroy` - capitalize `DataTable`

Comment: Tried it, but didn't help

Comment: Yes, because there is no such a method check the [**documentation**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/). If you want to destroy the table you can call `this.table.destroy()` if you have access to `this.table`

Comment: @codtex wow, this helped. I tried it before, but didn't work, not sure why. But there is a new problem - after destroying the table, new one not re-initializing... (updated question by full fucntion)

Comment: Hm, I I have found why it doesn't re-init, because destroy removes table from DOM. Is there any variants just to clear it?

Comment: You can check the [**examples from docs**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()#Examples) and also read the [**documentation for the destroy method**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()).  Also note that when you do `this.table.destroy('#searchResultsTable')` you are doing `this.table.destroy(true)`. This method allows only Boolean value

Comment: @codtex thank you for your help. It worked as I expected to. Could you write an answer instead of comment, then I can check it as answer

Comment: You are welcome. Yes I will post answer, too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clear data-table and re-draw it again you can do it with [**destroy()**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()) method and re-initialize the data-table which is the approach that you took also.

```
$.fn.dataTable.destroy('#searchResultsTable'); // This will not work
```

The above code didn't work because according to the [**documentation**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) there is no such a method.

So what you can do is use [**destroy()**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()) like `this.table.destroy()`. Note that `destroy()` method accepts optional Boolean parameter, which by default is `false`, meaning that the table will be restored to it's initial state(*so later we can re-initialize it*). If you pass `true` the table will be completely removed from the **DOM**

**A sample code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table,
      btnDestroy = $('#destroy'),
      btnReInit = $('#init'),
      btnRand = $('#random');

  init();

  btnDestroy.on('click', destroy);
  btnReInit.on('click', init);
  btnRand.on('click', randomData);

  function destroy() {
    try {
      table.destroy();
      btnDestroy.attr('disabled', true);
      btnReInit.attr('disabled', false);
      btnRand.attr('disabled', false);
    } catch (e) {console.log(e.message);}
  }

  function init() {

    table = $('#my-data-table').DataTable({
      retrieve: true,
      searching: false,
      paging: false,
      info: false,
      orderMulti: false,
      order: [
        [0, "asc"]
      ]
    });
    btnDestroy.attr('disabled', false);
    btnReInit.attr('disabled', true);
    btnRand.attr('disabled', true);
  }

  function randomData() {
    var tbody = $('#my-data-table tbody');
    tbody.html('');
    var rows = [];
    var iterations = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 3; // Random count rows
    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
      rows.push('<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td>user ' + i + '</td><td>' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 100 + '</td></tr>');
    }

    tbody.html(rows.join(''));
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<p>You can randomize the data before Re-Initialize</p>
<button type="button" id="destroy">Destroy</button>
<button type="button" id="init" disabled>Re-Initialize</button>
<button type="button" id="random" disabled>Random Data</button>

<table id="my-data-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>user 1</td>
      <td>34569</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>user 2</td>
      <td>137</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```